# How to find the oauth_verifier in Magento

Tags: api, magento, oauth

I've to use Magento Web API's using OAuth . I have created a Consumer with web panel and i've consumer key and consumer secret key. now i have to find the Access token . so i refered some material and came to run the following command

```
oauth \
  --verbose \
   --query-string \
   --consumer-key c9c60d4aaf670c86acee7e93bb776e45 \
   --consumer-secret 0a0b845eb7507de84c63740b15561568 \
   --access-token-url http://localhost/magento/oauth/token \
   --authorize-url http://localhost/magento/oauth/authorize \
   --request-token-url http://localhost/magento/oauth/initiate \
   authorize
```

The response came like

> Server appears to support OAuth 1.0a; enabling support.
>   Please visit this url to authorize:
>   http://localhost/magento/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=6a57c2e2d3f9883a94bfd2087dd95a89
>   Please enter the verification code provided by the SP (oauth_verifier):

Now i dont know where to find the verification code and how to use this.

Help me through this,. Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

its returned when you do as it requested **'Please visit this url to authorize:'** 
in your case its
**http://localhost/magento/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=6a57c2e2d3f9883a94bfd2087dd95a89**

just paste that in you browser, and it should take you to an authorize or reject page. (will now be invalid)
this is based on the **--authorize-url**

i need admin access, so i use
--authorize-url http://www.myhost.com//admin/oauth_authorize

Comment: when i hit http://www.myhost.com/admin/oauth_authorize im gertting your authorization is invalid